# How to: computed property with closure for array of structs

Tags: swift, closures

```
struct Grade {
let letter: String
let points: Double
let credits: Double
}

class Student {
var firstName: String
var lastName: String
var grades: [Grade] = []

init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
  self.firstName = firstName
  self.lastName = lastName
}

func recordGrade(_ grade: Grade) {
  grades.append(grade)
}
  var GPA: Double  {
      get{
          
      
  }
}
```

> I am trying to create a closure for GPA computed property that would go over an array of structs(`grades`) and sum the points of each `Grade` struct and then divide by the sum of `credits`. I tried `reduce` and I tried `forEach` and I got plenty of errors. I want to find out how to solve that with closures instead of for-loop. Any help would be appreciated

This is one of the variations that I tried:

```
var GPA: Double  {
       get{
       
               grades.reduce(0){
                   ($0.points + $1.points)/($0.credits + $0.credits)
               }
       }
   }
}
```

errors:

> Value of type 'Double' has no member 'credits'
> Value of type 'Double' has no member 'points'

Comment: Can you show the attempts that "got plenty of errors"? And also show the error messages.

Comment: Don't write `$0` and `$1`. Write the explicite `reduce` closure parameters. Once you make it work, you can use `$0` et `$1` if you want. But you'll see, that since you reduce to `0` (initial value), then the first parameter (`$0`) is a Double. Not a `Grade`, that's why you have that compiler error message.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your `var GPA: Double` you could do something like this where you can use a `tuple` to track both values and make a single pass across the Grades using `reduce`.

```
var GPA: Double {
    let totals = grades.reduce((points: 0.0, credits: 0.0)) { result, grade -> (Double, Double) in
        return (result.points + grade.points, result.credits + grade.credits)
    }

    return totals.points / totals.credits
}
```

Alternatively you can use a `forEach` and do it in the following way:

```
var GPA: Double {
    var totalPoints: Double = 0
    var totalGrades: Double = 0

    grades.forEach { grade in
        totalPoints += grade.points
        totalGrades += grade.credits
    }

    return totalPoints / totalGrades
}
```

You do not need to apply an explicit getter for your computed property, unless you are going to provide an explicit setter.

Though you may want to add some error handling to make sure that the credits value is non-zero otherwise you will get `Double.infinity`.

Comment: Note that division by zero will not lead to a crash, it will return `Double.infinity`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson That is true.

Answer (score 1):

```swift
struct Grade {
    let letter: String
    let points: Double
    let credits: Double
}

class Student {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var grades: [Grade] = []

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }

    func recordGrade(_ grade: Grade) {
        grades.append(grade)
    }

    var GPA: Double  {
        let sumPoints = grades.reduce(into: 0, { $0 += $1.points })
        let sumCredits = grades.reduce(into: 0, { $0 += $1.credits })
        return sumPoints / sumCredits
    }
}
```

Here you go :). First of all there is a closing bracket missing in your code. Maybe that's where all the errors came from.

The `reduce` function works as follows:
The first parameter `into: 0` means that `0` is your initial sum and you won't have to use another helper variable inside the block. `$0` refers to the current sum value and `$1` is your grade object of the current iteration.